# Inheritance approach in PACT

Tags: token, pact-lang, kadena

I want to create a set of coins implementing *fungible-v2* and a set of internal features. My approach has been to create an interface *mytoken* and to implement both *mytoken* and *fungible-v2* in *mytoken1*. I have also created a table for account balance and so on.

The problem is that if I want to create a new token *mytoken2* with tiny differences from *mytoken1* (maybe just the name), I have to copy all the contract (which is really huge in terms of line codes).

Another alternative would be to create another module with the common behaviour but in that case I believe I could find some issues with capability handling, module governance, etc. in calls between modules (and I will need to create the all functions to fulfill the public interfaces).

In Solidity there is the *abstract* and *extend* reserved words allowing to inherit common behavior.

Which would be the best approach in PACT?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid code duplication you can wrap the functions from a module `token` as base for your module `token1`, `token2`, ...

Stuart Popejoy wrote an extended example on how wrapping can be used:
https://medium.com/kadena-io/pact-tips-wrapper-contracts-7034be982c56